# Why expression after return's parenthesis is checked for lexical correctness, but is not evaluated?

Tags: r

Consider the following code:

```
a = function() {
  return (23)
}
b = function() {
  return (23) * 23
}
c = function() {
  return (23) * someUndefinedVariable
}
```

All of the above runs successfully (if called) and return 23.
I assumed that R ignores everything that goes after the closing parenthesis of `return`, but it does not really, because this code fails during code loading:

```
d = function() {
  return (23) something
}
```

My assumption is that in the latter example some lexer or parser fails. But in the former, expression is parsed as `(return(23))*some` (because `return` is treated like a function), but evaluation stops at `return` and therefore R does not try to find `some`.

Does that sounds ok? Is that the reason? Is such behavior intended? Can I enable some warnings so that interpreter tells me about such 'unreachable code'?

Comment: Why would you want to mess with redefining `c`? That should be equivalent to shifting into reverse as you're driving down the freeway.

Comment: Lazy evaluation. A variable won't be evaluated unless it needs to be used... and as soon as something is `return()`ed the function is over so nothing else needs to be used. For the last example, as BondedDust answered, it's invalid syntax, which is different.

Comment: @DavidArenburg exactly, I was numbering examples.

Comment: Hmmm how was my comment removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failure of this code:

```
d = function() {
  return (23) something
}
```

... has nothing to do with the prior code and everything to do with the inability to parse: `return (23) something`. Unlike the earlier misguided attempt to redefine `c` which had a valid/parseable function body, the `d`-body is incapable of being put into a functional form. The parser doesn't really stop at return(23) but rather after it tokenizes `something` and "realizes" that it is not a semicolon or an infix function name. So the R interpreter now has two expressions and no valid connector/separator between them.

The referenced objects inside R function bodies at the time of definition do not get evaluated or even checked for existence in the parameter list or outside the function. (R is not a compiler.)

Answer (score 3):

R parses the statement before it is evaluated:

```
parse(text = "funky <- function(x) {
        return(x) * dog
}")
```

returns:

```
expression(funky <- function(x) {
        return(x) * dog
})
```

However,

```
parse(text = "funky <- function(x) {
         return(x) dog
}")
```

returns:

```
Error in parse(text = "funky <- function(x) {\n        return(x) dog\n}") : 
  <text>:2:19: unexpected symbol
1: funky <- function(x) {
2:         return(x) dog
                     ^
```

In the above example, even though the variable `dog` doesn't exist (and comes after `return`), R is still able to `parse` it as it correct code.

Answer (score 3):

`return` is not just "treated like a function", it *is* a function. And anytime it's called, the code path will exit from whatever function you're in at that moment.

So that means that by the time `R` would have gotten to multiplying the result of `return` by 23, it's all over, that evaluation stops, and there are no errors or warnings to report (just like there are no warnings or errors when you return inside some `if` condition).

Whereas your last function simply cannot be parsed (which more or less means that the expression is put into a function tree), and so that (function) object can't be created.

Comment: No, at least 'no' to the material after the first sentence and my interpretation of the question as why the `d <-` assignment fails. The error would occur with any function.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. First two paragraphs are about functions a-c in OP.

Comment: Which it seemed as though the questioner understood and was accepting.